# A black line on 9patch background when scroll on a listview

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a problem with 9patch image. I using it as background of listview item. When I scroll listview, there are a black line on background (it is in red circle). When the listview is not scrolling, it's display well and has no black line.

Note: The big black bar is just use for censor my messages content.

[image: My 9patch image]

[image: When scrolling]

Answer (score 1):

Try disable ListView fadingEdge:

```
<ListView android:fadingEdge="none" />
```

Check out [this API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) to see how scrolling/fading works.